# GTK-Printing: detect if printer is configured/printing would work?

Tags: linux, printing, gtk, cairo

using following code I can print under Linux smoothly:

```
op = gtk_print_operation_new();
gtk_print_operation_set_allow_async(op,TRUE);
gtk_print_operation_set_n_pages(op, 1);
gtk_print_operation_set_unit (op,GTK_UNIT_MM);
g_signal_connect (op, "draw_page", G_CALLBACK(draw_page), NULL);
gtk_print_operation_run (op, GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_PRINT,NULL, NULL);
```

My problem: when printing would not be successful (e.g. because no printer is configured) draw_page() is not called but I do not have any feedback about failure. So: how can I check if printing will be done or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
void
gtk_print_operation_get_error (GtkPrintOperation *op,
                               GError **error);
```

> Call this when the result of a print operation is
>   GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_RESULT_ERROR, either as returned by
>   gtk_print_operation_run(), or in the “done” signal handler. The
>   returned GError will contain more details on what went wrong.